# How do I exclude directories when listing files?

Tags: ubuntu, shell, ls

How do I exclude directories when listing files in the current directory?

```
ls .
```

^ will include directories in the listing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this one:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d
```

Comment: keep it simple:
$ find . -type f

Comment: No. (1) it would be recursive, (2) it would not list symlinks. @Steve asked for equivalent of `ls .` without directories — and here it is.

Comment: Adding `-ls` or `-exec ls -l {} \;` would make it like `ls -l` without directories.

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -o -type l` could also add includes of symlinks beside files.

Comment: This was perfect for my needs except for leading `./` in the listing, but easily removed with `cut -c 3-`

Answer (score 23):

To get it exactly equivalent to `ls .` you need to not show hidden dirs.

`find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d -and -not -name '.*'`

and that still leaves you with './' prefixed to each filename.  That's not really an issue, but I think it's kinda ugly.  I went with:

`ls -p | grep -v '/$'`

And that will get you a listing that looks the same, and you can add additional `ls` arguments too.  Add a `--color=always` and you'll get your dircolors back, or `-a` to see hidden files.

I like Alexander's answer because he's actually depending on a filesystem characteristic of the file in question so it won't get fooled ever.  My answer will get fooled by a file that has a '/' as the last character in it's name.  But that seems like it's asking for trouble.

Comment: '-not' is GNU find related, as it is not POSIX compliant, it's better not to teach these options as an user could have "bad" habbits and feel lost on other UNIXes :)

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha what is the POSIX alternative to -not?

Answer (score 5):

try this:

> $ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f

or this:

> $ ls -p | egrep -v /$
>
> $ ls -la | egrep -v ^d

Answer (score 5):

Though it's an old post, but i thought this might help..

$ ls -l |grep -v ^d

It will list all the files including symlinks,character and block files.

Comment: This answer was already provided over a year before by jamzed, (making this visual noise.)

Answer (score 3):

The "find" solutions above lose some of the capabilities of **ls** - for example: list only files, sorted in descending modification time.

The "ls -p | grep" answers do not elegantly deal with other elements of ls such as -R should they be desired

The following answer, while more verbose, in my opinion reflects the truest **ls** behaviour and most flexibility for selecting "files only"

```
ls -t . | while read line; do
  if [ -f $line ]; then
    echo $line
  fi 
done
```

Simply replace the ls switches as desired and the result will be returned with files only. If links and other items are also required then minor rework would need to be done to the test for inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls $(file --no-pad  -F' '  * | grep -v directory | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

With this you can still use any other options `ls` usually takes.
Or... remove `-v` to list only directories.
Or... replace directory with any other filetype that `file` understands and reports, like ASCII, empty, ELF, and so on.

Comment: This doesn't work if any of the filenames to be listed contain spaces.

Comment: `ls -t .|while read f;do [ -f "$f" ]&& echo $f;done` is about 3x faster in my tests

Answer (score 0):

I was on a system where the `find` binary did not support `-not` and I ended up using:

```
ls|while read f;do [ -f "$f" ]&& echo $f;done
```

Advantages: 
Does not rely on anything other than `sh ls echo`
Is compatible with bash and dash
Can be changed to match other things, (such as directories) by changing `-f`
Is fastest than some of the answers and uses less RAM and CPU

Answer (score 0):

`ls -pd $PWD/* |grep -v /$ |xargs ls -l --color=always`